# expects parameter '@id', which was not supplied. the id is primary key and identity

Tags: c#, sql-server

I get this error:

> expects parameter '@id', which was not supplied. the id is primary key and identity

My code:

```
namespace se_up_de_in
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-R0N4ID3;Initial Catalog=DBTask2;Integrated Security=True");

        SqlCommand comm;
        SqlDataAdapter Adapter;

        DataTable Table = new DataTable();

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (comm = new SqlCommand("proc_insertid", conn))
            {
                comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                conn.Open();

                SqlParameter[] parameter = new SqlParameter[5];
                parameter[0] = new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
                parameter[0].Value = textBox5.Text;

                parameter[1] = new SqlParameter("@username", SqlDbType.NChar);
                parameter[1].Value = textBox1.Text;

                parameter[2] = new SqlParameter("@password", SqlDbType.NChar);
                parameter[2].Value = textBox2.Text;


                parameter[3] = new SqlParameter("@email", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                parameter[3].Value = textBox3.Text;


                parameter[4] = new SqlParameter("@Type", SqlDbType.NChar);
                parameter[4].Value = textBox4.Text;

                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

                comm.Parameters.AddRange(parameter);

                conn.Close();

                dataGridviewfill();
            }
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (comm = new SqlCommand("proc_Dlelete", conn))
            {
                comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                conn.Open();

                SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
                param = new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.NChar);
                param.Value = textBox5.Text;

                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                comm.Parameters.Add(param);

                conn.Close();

                dataGridviewfill();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_insert
     (@id INT,
      @username NCHAR(10),
      @password NCHAR(10),
      @email NVARCHAR(MAX),
      @Type NCHAR(10))
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ttask2 (id, username, password, email, Type)
    VALUES (@id, @username, @password, @email, @Type)
END
```

Comment: Ask Question

0


expects parameter '@id', which was not supplied. the id is primary key and identity

Comment: Shouldn't you add the parameters BEFORE executing the statement?

Comment: Try to give us some more context and explaining to us what exactly are you aiming for. Simply throwing code and an error message is not enough to help you or others that might have the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 1):

```
comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
comm.Parameters.AddRange(parameter);
```

Reverse these; you need to add the parameters before executing the command.

```
comm.Parameters.AddRange(parameter);
comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

(same for other places you use the command/parameters)